# codeigniter input

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, input

i want to do so then a person click on the input box it should hide the standard "custom" text

i have this

```
echo form_input('username', 'Username', 'class="login_input"');
```

how can i do with javascript that username get remove then clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This way, both onfocus and onblur event will work

```
//script tag starts
function myFocus(element) {
     if (element.value == element.defaultValue) {
       element.value = '';
     }
   }
   function myBlur(element) {
     if (element.value == '') {
       element.value = element.defaultValue;
     }
   }
//script tag ends


echo form_input('username', 'Username', 'class="login_input" onfocus="myFocus(this);" onblur="myBlur(this);" ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo form_input('username', 'Username', 'class="login_input" onfocus="this.value=\'\'"');
```

Comment: the problem is that if he type something and then click it, its gone

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo form_input('username', 'Username', 'class="login_input" onblur="if (this.value == \'\') {this.value = \'Custom\';}"  onfocus="if (this.value == \'Custom\') {this.value = \'\';}" value="Custom"');
```